# Where should I close Hibernate session object after showing results of mapped 2 tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I'm having `proxy initialisation-no session error` and I have figured out it is due to closing of Hibernate session object, before returning an Iterator containing all the records to be displayed. 
I have 2 tables:

```
Emp {
  eid int Primary Key,
  ename String,<br>
  did int (Foreign Key to Dept table);
}

Dept {
  did int,
  dname String;
}
```

I have created `POJO` classes using Netbeans Reverse Engineering wizard. Now I have show.jsp, which shows records and have a RegisterEmp.java which contains a method `public Iterator<Emp> getListOfUsers()` to fetch all such records, to be displayed on show.jsp.

The method is shown as follows:

```
   public Iterator<Emp> getListOfUsers(){
    List<Emp> list = null;
    Iterator<Emp> listIterator = null;
    try {
        sf = DbUtil.getSf(); //getting SessionFactory obj from DbUtil class
        s = sf.openSession(); //s is a session object
        Query query=s.createQuery("from Emp");            
        list=query.list();
        listIterator=list.iterator();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        //s.close(); //I figured this is giving me proxy initialisation- no session error
    }
    return listIterator;
}
```

And the code for show.jsp is:

```
<%@ page import="data.*, business.*"%>
<%@ page import ="java.util.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

     <title>Result Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
     <div id="container">
         <h1>Result Page</h1>

         <table border="2">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Emp ID</th>
                     <th>Emp Name</th>
                     <th>Department</th>
                     <th>Update Record</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 <%
                     int eid;
                     String ename, dept; 
                     RegisterEmp loginService = new RegisterEmp();
                     Iterator<Emp> itr = loginService.getListOfUsers();
                     while(itr.hasNext())
                     {
                        Emp e=(Emp)itr.next();
                        Dept d=e.getDept();
                        //out.println("  "+e.getEname()+ "  ");
                        //out.println("  "+d.getDname() + "  ");
                        eid = e.getEid();
                        ename = e.getEname();
                        dept = d.getDname();

                 %>
                 <tr>
                     <td><%=eid%></td>
                     <td><%=ename%></td>
                     <td><%=dept%></td>
                     <td><a href="updateviewform.jsp?id=<%=eid%>&ename=<%=ename%>&dept=<%=dept%>">Update</a></td>
                 </tr>
                 <%}%>
             <tbody>
         </table>    
         <br/>
     </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Since `show.jsp` would have access to HttpSession object and not Hibernate Session's object, I can't close Hibernate session object here too.

Where can I close it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would still close it in the service method, to prevent from any problems regarding a session left open.

Just eagerly fetch the needed dependencies while still being in the session context:

```
Query query=s.createQuery("select e from Emp e inner join fetch e.dept");
```

Comment: By your answer it means, I should close immediately after createQuery("from Emp"); But then when I'll try to show in show.jsp, I would still have the same error as before.

Comment: In  the finally clause. And if you fetch all the dependent entities while session is active, then should not have a problem

Comment: The problem is I have to fetch in show.jsp, so as to display it there.

Comment: there will be no session in jsp and there should not be. Try my query and lets see where we will go from there

Comment: Where do I have to add this query? In show.jsp? I'm sorry I could not understand your answer.

Comment: Sorry, was a bit too fast with my thoughts. Just replace `Query query=s.createQuery("from Emp"); ` with my query

Comment: You're the man! Thank you. I replaced the query, while letting s.close() in finally section of my getListOfUsers() method. 
But I can't understand what the query is doing? Like what is the role of fetch here? And how is the error not coming now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143309/discussion-between-sahil-dhawan-and-maciej-kowalski).

Comment: It's a vast topic.. try to read about hibernate proxy objects and lazy and eager fetching. After reading dee articles you should get the idea behind those concepts